# Phantom buffers keep appearing after using :Texplore command

Tags: vim

When I use `:Texplore` command the buffer I was in while executing it gets duplicated. It is identical to the buffer I was in except (1) it has different slashes:
The original buffer name: `scp://login@server.com//path_to_file`
The phantom buffer name: `scp:/login@server.com/path_to_file`
and (2) it is empty. This doesn't happen if I work with local files.

So after opening and closing many files in this manner I end up with a lot of empty buffers and it becomes very hard to handle a list of buffers. What can I do to prevent these phantoms from filling my buffer list? Is it a bug or feature?

Comment: That `:Texplore` command comes from the _netrw_ plugin that ships with Vim. Please submit any issues to the plugin author, Chip Campbell; you'll find his email address at `:h pi_netrw.txt`.

Comment: Also, please try out the latest alpha version from [his website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/); maybe it's already fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this problem. Instead of using `:Texplore` command I use `:tabnew` with the directory path provided by the `Ctrl+r %` command - inserting from the % register that contains the name of the current file.